# Translate (localise) \theendnotes heading

Tags: sectioning, endnotes, naming

I'm using the `endnotes` package for enabling endnotes within my document. With an English document it is no problem but when I'm using it within a German document and added the `ngerman` package, the heading created by `\theendnotes` still reads "*Notes*" and not the German equivalent "*Anmerkungen*".

I suspect I need to redefine a command specifying the heading explicitly, but which command do I need to redefine?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, after grepping the sty file I found this:

```
% JK  Introduced \notesname in the spirit of international \LaTeX.
% JK  \notesname is set per default to be {Notes}, but can easily
% JK  be redifined, e.g. for german language
% JK  \renewcommand{\notesname}{Anmerkungen}
```

Nothing to add, I suppose;)

(My previous answer, with `\renewcommand{\theendnotes}{Anmerkungen}`, was obviously wrong - sorry.)

Comment: This overrides the whole command so only this text is displayed. The list of notes does not appear anymore.

Comment: :) Thank you for this. Couldn't have been easier.