# "You are using two French options for Babel" due to the use of \theendnotes with frenchle?

Tags: lyx, babel, endnotes

While compiling to pdf a LyX document that uses packages frenchle and endnotes, I get: "You are using two French options for Babel" when I try to generate the pdf.

The solution is given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24877/translate-localise-theendnotes-heading) for German:

> % JK  Introduced \notesname in the spirit of international \LaTeX.
>
> % JK  \notesname is set per default to be {Notes}, but can easily
>
> % JK be redifined, e.g. for german language
>
> % JK \renewcommand{\notesname}{Anmerkungen}

But after several tries, I realy don't know how to apply it. "Anmerkungen" means "notes" in english and "notes" in french, so I imagine I should not need it anyway.

If I add `\renewcommand{\notesname}{Notes}` in the preambul, it changes nothing.
If I add it in the document in a TeX box before the one for \theendnotes, or in the same box, it changes nothing.

Here is a MWE:

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass scrbook
\begin_preamble
\usepackage[english,frenchle]{babel}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
fixltx2e
initials
foottoend
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding latin9
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a5paper
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 1cm
\topmargin 1cm
\rightmargin 1cm
\bottommargin 1cm
\secnumdepth 2
\tocdepth 2
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 2
\paperpagestyle default
\bullet 0 2 5 -1
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
test
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
blabla
\begin_inset Foot
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
my note
\end_layout

\end_inset

 bla.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\align left

\lang french
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
theendnotes
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having build another MWE from scratch, it appears that my original document has a `\lang french` in the *endnotes* block:

```
\begin_layout Standard
\align left

\lang french
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
theendnotes
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout
```

Suppressing it in a text editor solves the problem.