# No Heading for Endnotes

Tags: sectioning, endnotes, headline

I would like to use XeLaTeX to write papers according to MLA8, but for that the automatic heading created by `\theendnotes` is in the way. There is already an explanation on how to change the heading ([Translate (localise) \theendnotes heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24877/translate-localise-theendnotes-heading)) via, for example, `\renewcommand{\theendnotes}{Anmerkungen}`. However, if I leave the last bracket empty, there is no headline text, but it still takes up space as if something was there. How can I change this so that I can simply use

```
\begin{center}
Notes
\end{center}
```

Here's my minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\geometry{top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{} 
\chead{} 
\rhead{Name \thepage} 
\lfoot{} 
\cfoot{} 
\rfoot{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote
\def\footnotetext{\endnotetext[\number\numexpr\value{endnote}+1]}
\let\footnotemark\endnotemark

\renewcommand{\notesname}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}

Name\\
Professor\\
Class\\
Date\\

\begin{center}
Testing%
    \footnote{Formatting in accordance with MLA8.}
\end{center}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

Test

\newpage

\begin{center}
Notes
\end{center}

\theendnotes

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\enoteheading}{}` removes the heading of the endnotes completely.

Comment: thank you so much! that worked like a charme! do you want to claim that answer?